# Create an Autofac service around a background thread or task

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library, autofac

I have a WebAPI app that needs to run some tasks every 30 minutes or so. How can I create a service object that encapsulates this processing and starts on application start. I need also to be able to inject this service into some of the controllers. I also need to some of my other Autofac services when the task runs (every 30 min.).

Comment: What have you got so far and what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use NCron (https://code.google.com/p/ncron/). NCron is a light-weight library for building and deploying scheduled background jobs.

Also, you can use Autofac integration to perform dependency injection for your NCron jobs (https://code.google.com/p/ncron/wiki/DependencyInjection).